# sys.argv can't get arguments in VSCode debugging mode

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, vscode-debugger

I am currently learning a code by debugging. The code uses sys.argv to get the arguments from the command line. I have already added "args" in the launch.json file. However, the len(sys.argv) is still 1, which is only the name of the script. How to get the arguments in debugging mode in VSCode? Thanks!

This is my launch.json file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "args": ["xx1", "xx2"]
        }
    ]
}
```

The arguments xx1 and xx2 are parallel arguments, not key and value, and there's no parser in the code. Nevertheless, I tried "--xx1", "--xx2" as well, the length is still 1. Would appreciate it if somebody could help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your debugger configuration seems correct. Make sure this is the one that is selected in the debug tab:

[image]

Try with a simple python file containing only:

```py
import sys
print ("Number of arguments:", len(sys.argv), "arguments")
print ("Argument List:", str(sys.argv))
```

In VSCode, press F1 and search for `Python:Debug Python File`, or directly hit the green triangle in the picture above, with your python file opened. You should see a similar output in the terminal:

```bash
/usr/bin/env /mnt/c/Users/mat/draft_linux/venv/bin/python /home/mat/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.10.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 60649 -- /mnt/c/Users/mat/draft_linux/toto.py xx1 xx2 
Number of arguments: 3 arguments
Argument List: ['/mnt/c/Users/mlg/Documents/07_useful_repos_n_scripts/03_draft_linux/toto.py', 'xx1', 'xx2']
```